# Xamarin Forms Android Vertical ScrollView cutting off elements

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a page that consists of one vertical only ScrollView.  The problem I'm having is when the content goes beyond the bottom of the page all content below the fold is cut off when scrolling.  The odd thing is if I rotate the device, everything renders correctly, and if I rotate back everything gets rendered.

This only happens on Android, iOS and UWP everything works fine. The content of the ScrollView is below.  I've tried adding Margin="0" to all of the children as suggested in a StackOverflow question but it didn't help.

In the code behind, I add 0 to n Grids to the workContainer StackLayout.  Each grid is rendered in a ScrollView that has horizontal only scrolling.  The effect is used to trigger a "page rendered" type of event.

```
 <ScrollView Orientation="Vertical" x:Name="verticalScroller" IsClippedToBounds="False" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <StackLayout>
            <Grid Margin="15,6,15,6">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width = "1*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width = "4.5*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width = "1*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="Start">
                    <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2"
                            Style="{StaticResource BlueRithmPrimaryButtonStyle }"
                            Text="{x:Static resourceStrings:AppResources.ButtonAddNote}"
                            Clicked="AddNoteButton_Clicked"/>
                    <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Margin="5, 0, 0, 0"
                            IsVisible="{Binding ParentType, Converter={StaticResource ParentTypeAndRoleToVisibility}}"
                            Style="{StaticResource BlueRithmPrimaryButtonStyle }"
                            Text="{x:Static resourceStrings:AppResources.ButtonAddIssue}"
                            Clicked="AddIssueButton_Clicked"/>
                </StackLayout>
                <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
                        Text="{Binding HeaderTaskCategory}"
                        MaxLines="1"
                        FontSize="20"
                        TextColor="White"
                        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                        HorizontalOptions="Center" />
                <StackLayout Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"
                        Orientation="Horizontal" 
                        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                        HorizontalOptions="Center">
                    <Label FontSize="20"
                            Style="{StaticResource EditLabelStyle}"
                            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                            HorizontalOptions="Center"
                            IsVisible="{Binding Task.AssignedToId, Converter={StaticResource UserIdToVisible}}">
                        <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="StatusEdit_Tapped"/>
                        </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                    </Label>
                    <Label x:Name="StatusLabel"
                            IsVisible="{Binding Task.AssignedToId, Converter={StaticResource UserIdToVisible}}"
                            FontSize="20"
                            Padding="6,0,6,0"
                            TextColor="{Binding Status, Converter={StaticResource StatusToTextColor}}"
                            Text="{Binding Status, Converter={StaticResource StatusToText}}" 
                            BackgroundColor="{Binding Status, Converter={StaticResource StatusToColor}}"
                            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                            HorizontalOptions="Center" >
                        <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="StatusEdit_Tapped"/>
                        </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                    </Label>
                    <Label IsVisible="{Binding Task.AssignedToId, Converter={StaticResource UserIdToVisibleReverse}}"
                            FontSize="20"
                            Padding="6,0,6,0"
                            TextColor="{Binding Status, Converter={StaticResource StatusToTextColor}}"
                            Text="{Binding Status, Converter={StaticResource StatusToText}}" 
                            BackgroundColor="{Binding Status, Converter={StaticResource StatusToColor}}"
                            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                            HorizontalOptions="Center" >
                    </Label>
                </StackLayout>
            </Grid>
            <Label Text="{Binding DescriptionHeader}"
                        Padding="25,0,6,0"
                        FontSize="18"
                        TextColor="White"
                        VerticalOptions="Center"
                        HorizontalOptions="Start" />
            <StackLayout x:Name="workContainer"></StackLayout>
            <StackLayout  Margin="20,10,20,40">
                <BoxView HeightRequest="4" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Color="White" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="7" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="28"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <!-- Assigned To -->
                    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
                               Margin="0,2"
                               Text="{x:Static resourceStrings:AppResources.LabelAssignedTo}"
                               TextColor="White"
                               VerticalOptions="Center"
                               HorizontalOptions="End" />
                    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"
                               Margin="0,2"
                               Text="{Binding AssignedTo}"
                               TextColor="White"
                               VerticalOptions="Center"
                               HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
                    <!-- Date Due -->
                    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"
                               Margin="0,2"
                               Text="{x:Static resourceStrings:AppResources.LabelDueDate}"
                               TextColor="White"
                               VerticalOptions="Center"
                               HorizontalOptions="End"/>
                    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"
                               Margin="0,2"
                               Text="{Binding DateDue}"
                               TextColor="White"
                               VerticalOptions="Center"
                               HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
                    <!-- Hours -->
                    <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"
                               Margin="0,2"
                               Text="{x:Static resourceStrings:AppResources.LabelHours}"
                               TextColor="White"
                               VerticalOptions="Center"
                               HorizontalOptions="End"/>
                    <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2"
                               Margin="0,2"
                               Text="{Binding Hours}"
                               TextColor="White"
                               VerticalOptions="Center"
                               HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
                    <!-- Entered By -->
                    <Label Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0"
                               Margin="0,2"
                               Text="{x:Static resourceStrings:AppResources.LabelEnteredBy}"
                               TextColor="White"
                               VerticalOptions="Center"
                               HorizontalOptions="End"/>
                    <Label Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2"
                               Margin="0,2"
                               Text="{Binding EnteredBy}"
                               TextColor="White"
                               VerticalOptions="Center"
                               HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
                    <!-- Date Entered -->
                    <Label Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0"
                               Margin="0,2"
                               Text="{x:Static resourceStrings:AppResources.LabelDateEntered}"
                               TextColor="White"
                               VerticalOptions="Center"
                               HorizontalOptions="End"/>
                    <Label Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2"
                               Margin="0,2"
                               Text="{Binding DateEntered}"
                               TextColor="White"
                               VerticalOptions="Center"
                               HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
                    <!-- Last Edit By -->
                    <Label Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0"
                               Margin="0,2"
                               Text="{x:Static resourceStrings:AppResources.LabelLastEditBy}"
                               TextColor="White"
                               VerticalOptions="Center"
                               HorizontalOptions="End"/>
                    <Label Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="2"
                               Margin="0,2"
                               Text="{Binding LastEditBy}"
                               TextColor="White"
                               VerticalOptions="Center"
                               HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
                    <!-- Last Edit -->
                    <Label Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="0"
                               Margin="0,2"
                               Text="{x:Static resourceStrings:AppResources.LabelLastEditDate}"
                               TextColor="White"
                               VerticalOptions="Center"
                               HorizontalOptions="End"/>
                    <Label Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="2"
                               Margin="0,2"
                               Text="{Binding LastEdit}"
                               TextColor="White"
                               VerticalOptions="Center"
                               HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
                    <!-- Completed By -->
                    <Label Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="0"
                               Margin="0,2"
                               Text="{x:Static resourceStrings:AppResources.LabelMarkedCompletedBy}"
                               TextColor="White"
                               VerticalOptions="Center"
                               HorizontalOptions="End"/>
                    <Label Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="2"
                               Margin="0,2"
                               Text="{Binding CompletedBy}"
                               TextColor="White"
                               VerticalOptions="Center"
                               HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
                    <!-- Completed Date -->
                    <Label Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="0"
                               Margin="0,2"
                               Text="{x:Static resourceStrings:AppResources.LabelDateCompleted}"
                               TextColor="White"
                               VerticalOptions="Center"
                               HorizontalOptions="End"/>
                    <Label Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="2"
                               Margin="0,2"
                               Text="{Binding CompletedDate}"
                               TextColor="White"
                               VerticalOptions="Center"
                               HorizontalOptions="Start">
                        <Label.Effects>
                            <effects:ViewLifecycleEffect Loaded="Page_Loaded"></effects:ViewLifecycleEffect>
                        </Label.Effects>
                    </Label>
                </Grid>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: for the grid rows Height="1*" = 1%, try "33.33*" if you want 1/3 of the screen

Comment: As Nick Kovalsky suggested you can replace the row defention heights to  "* , * ,*"

Comment: `0 to n Grids to the workContainer StackLayout. Each grid is rendered in a ScrollView` - so you have ScrollViews inside of other containers, all inside of a surrounding ScrollView?  That's tricky to get right. My hypothesis is off-screen ScrollViews are given 0 height. Show the XAML for one of the Grids you add to `workContainer`. And add a button somewhere you can press after it has re-laid-out the screen with the Grids. Breakpoint in button code - examine heights.

Comment: I can't have a static height on anything, the grids need to expand and there can be 0 to many grids.

@ToolmakerSteve - Correct, the requirement is that the page must scroll vertically as a whole, but each grid must scroll horizontally.  The scrollviews aren't rendering with a height of 0 offscreen, they are getting cut off by the screen.  I've checked the heights with the grid's size changed, layout changed and measure invalidated.  Here is a video: http://candnbrett.com/android.mp4

The problem appears to be related to the async "Page_Loaded" effect (hack) to render the grids.

Comment: Please **Show the XAML (or code) for one of the Grids you add to workContainer. Also show the code that adds the Grids to workContainer.**  I agree that there is some limitation involving that effect. I believe you can work around the limitation with some coding; but I can't quite picture the solution yet. You will make a custom override of either the layout method or the measure method that layout calls. Google for tutorial describing performing custom layout. OR maybe you need to **force another layout call asynchronously**, after the effect completes. OR manually calc some needed height.